# Write to SDCard file fails without exception

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have gone through multiple threads about SDcard file writing problems, but could not see a answer that would help me.

1. I have used

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest for  node.

2. Following code creates a file but doesn't write to it. Writer never throws an exception either. When I go back to SDCard and see the file created is of 0 kb. ( which is due to createnew function) 
3. SDCard shows the file created with these permissions ----rwxr-x ( write not being there for others )
4. The behaviour is same on emulator or devices liek ASUS pad or Acer Iconia devices.

What is the regular way applications create files with content on SDCard from an Android application ?

```
if(isExternalStorageWritable()) {
    File testFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),Filename);
    try {
        if (testFile.createNewFile()) {
            Log.i(TAG + ": createSdcardFile","Empty file on external storage created");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                   openFileOutput(Filename, MODE_APPEND)));
            out.write(Content);
            out.close();
            Log.i(TAG + ": createSdcardFile","Content to new file created");
            created = true;
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Unable to create/write to new file on external storage. Terminating testCDMReadPositive");
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

4.Using mode **MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE** gives same result i.e. a 0kb file on SDCard

5. Anyone with experience in writing files on externalstorage ( /mnt/sdcard ) would know how to do this. Any help or direction, highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid suggestion, but did you delete the old testfile before the new run? Because your `if` clause will prevent writing to the file if it already existed.